# react hooks with redux, state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a simple section in which on click I would like to change the redux state

Here is my solution, demo.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import actions from "store/actions";
function Demo() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleCampaigns = () => {
    dispatch(actions.sliderActions.setIndex(1)); // open a slider containing slider component
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="sample"
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(actions.sliderActions.setName("campaigns_card")); // change the sate of cardName
          handleCampaigns();
        }}
      >
        Change redux state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

Here is the slider component which contains a slider

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector} from "react-redux";

function Slider() {
  const defaultName = useSelector((state) => state.sliderReducer.name);
  const [cardName, setCardName] = useState(defaultName);
  console.log("card name", cardName);

  return (
    <>
          <div>Card Name: {cardName}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Slider;
```

Here are reducer actions

```
const setName = items => {
    return {
        type: "SET_NAME",
        payload: items
    }
}
const exports = {
    setName
}

export default exports
```

and here is reducer

```
const initialState = {
  name: "social_card"
};
const sliderReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case "SET_NAME":
      return {...state, name: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default sliderReducer;
```

Now when I click the button to change the redux state in the console its shows the default state
`card name... social_card`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not state:

```
function Slider() {
  const cardName = useSelector((state) => state.sliderReducer.name);

  // remove the below line
  // const [cardName, setCardName] = useState(defaultName); 
  console.log("card name", cardName);

  return (
    <>
          <div>Card Name: {cardName}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

State is for some data your component owns. The data you are looking for is owned by redux, not your component, therefore it's not state.

What happens is the first time your `Slider` component gets the data from the store, it sets it as state. Whenever the name updates, your component does re-render, but it rerenders with the same state.

Solution: don't use state.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your
  `const [cardName, setCardName] = useState(defaultName);`
line.
That `cardName` will be set to `defaultName` on intitialization and never change, because `useState` works that way.

Generally, there is no reason for that line at all. Just do

`const cardName = useSelector((state) => state.sliderReducer.name);`